# Flink streaming Kinesis to Hudi not writing any data

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink, apache-hudi

I'm trying out PyFlink for streaming data from Kinesis into Hudi format, but can't figure out why it is not writing any data. I hope that maybe someone can provide any pointers.

Versions: Flink 1.15.4, Python 3.7, Hudi 0.13.0

I use streaming table environment

```
configuration = Configuration()
env_settings = (
    EnvironmentSettings.new_instance()
        .in_streaming_mode()
        .with_configuration(configuration)
        .build()
)
table_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(environment_settings=env_settings)
```

This is my schema

```
def get_test_table_schema() -> Schema:
    return (Schema.new_builder()
            .column("uuid", DataTypes.STRING().not_null())
            .column("updated_at", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP().not_null())
            .column("shard_key", DataTypes.STRING().not_null())
            .primary_key("uuid")
            .build())
```

This is how I define the output sink

```
table_env.create_table(
    "test_table",
    TableDescriptor.for_connector("hudi")
        .schema(get_test_table_schema())
        .option("path", "file://mypath/hudi/test.table")
        .option("table.primaryKey", "uuid")
        .option("table.preCombineField", "updated_at")
        .partitioned_by("shard_key")
        .build()
)
```

Manually inserting some data works and creates the files in the output path

```
result = table_env.execute_sql("""insert into test_table values
    ('1',TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:01', 'par1'),
    ('2',TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:02', 'par1'),
    ('3',TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:03', 'par2');
""")
```

The job in Flink UI finishes and `stream_write: test_table` tasks shows some data was written.

[image: Manual data with few examples in Flink UI]

However, if I stream the records from a source such as Kinesis:

```
table_env.create_table("kinesis", get_kinesis_source())
input_table = table_env.from_path("kinesis")
input_table.execute_insert("test_table")
```

I can see the records are retrieved, but never written to Hudi

[image: Kinesis source in Flink UI]

There are no exceptions, nothing seems broken. I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was not just pushing enough data to the pipeline.
I also reduced [`write.batch.size`](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/configurations/#writebatchsize) from default 256MB to 1MB and started seeing the updates in the target path.

```
table_env.create_table(
    "test_table",
    TableDescriptor.for_connector("hudi")
        .schema(get_test_table_schema())
        .option("path", "file://mypath/hudi/test.table")
        .option("table.primaryKey", "uuid")
        .option("table.preCombineField", "updated_at")
        .option("write.batch.size", "1")
        .partitioned_by("shard_key")
        .build()
)
```